# Pythonic way to write a function which modifies a list?

Tags: python

In python function arguments are passed by object reference. 
This means the simplest code to modify a list will modify the object itself.

```
a = [1,2,3]

def remove_one(b):
    b.remove(1)

remove_one(a)
print(a)
```

The method `remove_one` returns nothing. If that was a public method one has to assume it will modify the object and isn't thread safe inside the method.

---

A second approach would be to structure the code snippet like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]

def remove_one(b):
    b.remove(1)
    return(b)

print(remove_one(a[:]))
```

Here the content of a wasn't modified and a new list is returned. This puts a lot of responsibility on the method caller.

---

Then again `list comprehensions`, the pythonic approach of modifying list contents always create a new object.

```
a = [1,2,3]

def remove_one(b):
    b = [num for num in b if b!=1]
    return(b)

print(remove_one(a))
```

---

It isn't clear to me if there is a "pythonic" way to do it so I'll make some assumptions to be challenged:

- It's safer to assume that a function taking a mutable object will modify it's content
- There is a reason why list comprehensions don't also directly modify the object. I just don't know it
- The "pythonic" way to write functions that use list comprehensions to modify the mutable argument isn't clear

Comment: You don't have to use a list comprehension, but if you don't want to modify the object, you have to create a new one yourself somehow

Comment: The last piece of code isn't equivalent to the other two because it'll remove _all_ occurrences of `1` in the list, not _the first one_, as `remove` does. So you should probably just call `your_list.remove(1)` whenever you want to remove something from the list instead of wrapping this in another function.

Comment: That's why you add doc strings to your functions, so the caller knows by reading the docs what's gonna happen.

Comment: Note, your list comprehension version is not making an equivalent modification, although that doesn't seem relevant

Comment: Typically you just name your function to express what is does, `sorted()` vs `list.sort()` is a good example on how differentiate between those two approaches (returning new value vs mutating object state). To use list comprehension **and** change list "in-place" you can use a trick of replacing all elements in argument list with new values, e.g. `b[:] = [num for num in b if num != -1]`

Comment: IMHO changing mutable arguments is not pythonic already (explicit is better than implicit). Making a copy of b (`local_b = b.copy()`), changing (`local_b.remove(1)`) and returning it looks more explicit

Comment: The first and last choices are what most Python classes do. Either mutate and return `None`, or return a new value without modifying the original. Don't do #2.

Comment: Would an answer to this question be primarily opinion-based?

Comment: @chepner generally, built-in will not modify an *argument* though, although there are a few exceptions (heapq)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. Though the same reasoning applies (in most cases); you already have a reference to the original, so there's no particular need for the function to return the same references. (Though it does let you pass an anonymous object, like `b = remove_one([1,2,3])`, with `b` now `[2,3]`.  I'm divided on whether that's a good use-case to support.)

Comment: @Marat But there are examples within the python standard library itself where functions modify their argument(s). See, for example, [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle). There are pros and cons to each method; I think the most important thing here is documenting what the function does.

Comment: @chepner I fall firmly into the camp of that being an antipattern. Function arguments should not be mutates.

Comment: Why not write your first example as `remove_one_in_place`? This way is *explicit* that the function modifies the the mutable argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: If you modify an argument, do not return it.

---

> `list.sort()` sorts the list in place. In order to remind you of that fact, it does not return the sorted list.
>
> [Design and History FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list)

It is idiomatic to indicate whether you modify an argument by not returning it. For example, your first case is correct, your second is not:

```
def remove_one(b):
    b.remove(1)  # modify, do not return
```

If you do not modify an argument but create a copy, you must `return` the copy for the operation to be meaningful:

```
def one_removed(b):
    c = b.copy()  # create new object...
    c.remove(1)
    return c      # ...and return it
```

It is common for function/method names to reflect whether they actively modify their argument. Modifying functions tend to use active verbs, whereas non-modifying functions tend to use passive verbs or adjectives.

---

There is no "pythonic" choice whether to modify the argument or not - operating on the original or a copy are two fundamentally different operations. Both are valid depending on the use-case.

```
>>> items = [4, 3, 10, 2, 5]
>>> sorted(items)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
>>> items.sort()
>>> items
[2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
```

In general, mutating an argument is faster in Python, whereas creating a new result is easier to reason about.
In specific, comprehensions represent [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) operations ([namely `map` and `filter`](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)) -- they are designed not to modify their iterable.

---

Whether to return an argument due to modification *only concerns said argument*. For example, `list.pop` modifies the list and does not return it -- however, it does return the popped element.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me your not really looking for a simple element delete but rather a more complex mutation the list can have. If you are, however, a simple call to `.delete()` is what you're looking for.

On more complex mutations, one good example case study is the `heapq` module from the standard lib. And they do it pretty poorly IMHO. Lets see.

```py
import heapq

q = [5, 6, 3]

heapq.heapify(q)      # this mutates q
a = heapq.heappop(q)  # this aswell
```

*If you must know, the heap queue algorithm keeps the lowest item first in the list. So `q` is now `[5, 6]` and `a` is `3`.*

This is similar to what you have, and it is in the standard lib. Whatever you make of that.

However, I strongly disagree with this convention. All calls to  the `heapq` module functions will require passing that `q` as the first argument, and sometimes `q` is mutated . Yet `q` itself is never returned.

This is the exact problem a class solves. So why avoid a class?

```py
import heapq

class HeapQ(list):
    def __init__(self, a_list):
        super().__init__(a_list)  # calling the base `list()`
        heapq.heapify(self)

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self)

    def push(self, value):
        heapq.heappush(self, value)
```

And the calling convention is a bit more logical.

```py
>>> q = HeapQ([5, 6, 3])
>>> a = q.pop()
>>> q
[5, 6]
>>> a
3
```

This is way more pythonic, and with less surprises. Mutations on `q` are not surprising, every mutation is a call on `q`. `q.pop()`, `q.push(0)`, both mutate `q`.

*I actually do a more elaborate version of this all the time I need the `heapq` module.*